# How to Validate timestamp in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a naive in rails, I am trying to validate `to_date_timestamp` by using below mentioned code in `Transaction::ListingIntr`.I want to check for to_date_timestamp, my requirement is to_date_timestamp should be less than the current timestamp.This code is working fine on local machine. But when I deploy this on production value of Time.zone.now.to_i + 1 is always fixed to time when I deployed the code(used in `less_than_or_equal_to: Time.zone.now.to_i + 1`).Could not figure out why this is happening. Please help me on this.

```
class Transactions::ListingIntr < ApplicationInteraction
  object :user
  string :type, :sort_by, :query, default: nil
  integer :from_date_timestamp, :to_date_timestamp, default: nil
  string :currency, default: nil


  validates :to_date_timestamp,
            numericality: { greater_than: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: Time.zone.now.to_i + 1, allow_blank: true }

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to add `custom validation` that will convert time to first `utc` and then it will validate `to_date_timestamp`.

```
validate :check_to_date_timestamp 

def check_to_date_timestamp
  if to_date_timestamp.present? && (to_date_timestamp.utc.to_i < 0 || to_date_timestamp.utc.to_i > Time.now.utc.to_i + 1)
    errors.add(:base, "to_date_timestamp is not valid")
  end            
end
```

Comment: क्या बात हे मनीष जी, नही  मानोगे। Keep it up.

Answer (score -1):

Please add following line according to your time zone in application.rb file

```
config.time_zone = 'Mumbai'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```